# Call to a member function createToken() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-7

I am newbie to laravel api and laravel passport,and I know this is an old issue, but no answer helped me.I am using laravel passport for api
Registration,login working fine, but logout giving and error

**Here Is My Registraion Code**

```
 public function register (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'UserName' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'UserFullName' => 'string|max:255',
            'UserEmail' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'UserPhone' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'Password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()], 422);
        }
        if ($request['UserPhone']==Null) { // will check for empty string, null values, see php.net about it
            $request['UserPhone'] = NULL;
        }
        $request['Password']=Hash::make($request['Password']);
        $request['remember_token'] = Str::random(10);
        $request['UserType'] = $request['UserType'] ? $request['UserType']  : 1;
        //return response($request, 200);
        $user = User::create($request->toArray());
        $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
        //return response($token, 200);
        $response['data']= $user;
        $response['data']['token'] = $token;
        return response($response, 200);
    }
```

**My Login Code**

```
    public function login (Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'UserEmail' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'Password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response(['errors'=>$validator->errors()->all()], 422);
        }
        $user = User::where('UserEmail', $request->UserEmail)->first();
        if ($user) {
            if (Hash::check($request->Password, $user->Password)) {
                $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
                $response['data']= $user;
                $response['data']['token'] = $token;
                return response($response, 200);
            } else {
                $response = ["message" => "Password mismatch"];
                return response($response, 422);
            }
        } else {
            $response = ["message" =>'User does not exist'];
            return response($response, 422);
        }
    }
```

**My Logout Code**

```
public function logout (Request $request) {
        //return $request->Authorization;
        $token = $request->user()->token();
        //return $token;
        $token->revoke();
        $response = ['message' => 'You have been successfully logged out!'];
        return response($response, 200);
    }
```

**Postman Response**

```
"message": "Call to a member function createToken() on null",
    "exception": "Error",
```

Comment: It looks like your logout API is not calling logout function, but calling login/register function. Check whether logout function is called or not, and if yes, till which point the function executes without any error. so you can find the exact line throwing the error

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.i am not sure what do you mean by logout function, if i am not wrong you taking about laravel Auth::logout, i think that is used for web session. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was of Authorization it seems all api of post with authorization header should go through with auth check,I move my logout route inside middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api']],function(){
Route::get('/companies', 'CompanyController@index')->name('companies');
});
```

but I am not sure why it does not work with if(Auth:check){
...further revoke code
...
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use this route group and it will work

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth:api']],function(){
    Route::post('/logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout');    
});
```